# How do you export settings from the Database Publishing Wizard?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, settings, databasepublishingwizard

I'm using the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard) in VS2008 to push changes to my hosting provider.  It doesn't look like those settings go with the project (which seems a little silly to me), but rather they go with the machine.

On each new machine that I'd like to publish from I need to go through the process of digging up my database settings.

**Is there a way to backup/export/save these settings to a file?**

If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm ... it appears that the publishing wizard [uses 2 config files for it's application configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx):

> The Publish Database Wizard uses the
>   files *user.config* and *hoster.config* to
>   store configuration information. The
>   directory in which these files are
>   stored must have the appropriate NTFS
>   file system permissions set. These
>   files contain user names and encrypted
>   passwords. The passwords are encrypted
>   by using DPAPI.
>
> **user.config File**
>
> This file stores persisted host and
>   configuration settings for the Publish
>   Database Wizard. The user.config file
>   is located at %SystemDrive%\Documents
>   and Settings\%Username%\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Publishing
>   Wizard\user.config.
>
> **hoster.config File**
>
> This file stores options about Web
>   service addresses, user names, and
>   databases for shared hosting
>   providers. The hoster.config file is
>   located at %SystemDrive%\Documents and
>   Settings\%Username%\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Publishing
>   Wizard\hoster.config.

I'm trying to access these files in Vista (with VS2008 and SQL Express installed) and striking out.  I'll keep you posted.

***Update:***  Looks like I didn't have the Publishing Wizard installed after all.  After grabbing the [version for VS2008 here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=119368), and then installing (and don't worry -- you won't see any indication it's getting installed, but it does).... and THEN setting up my first database using the wizard, it looks like there are indeed some settings stored uder the 'Application Data' directory listed above.  However, it looks like it's just a user.config, and then an XML file for each database configured.  I believe you can backup each of these files for later use.